# How can I check browser smooth scrolling support via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, smoothing

How can I check browser smooth scrolling support via Javascript?
Or how can I disable smooth support scrolling and enable fixed scrolling (without disabling scrolling in divs with overflow:auto and textarea)?

Comment: what is a smooth support scrolling? if is a feature from specific javascript library it must have a method to check for it already or you might be able to add it.

Comment: Native optional browser feature. For example smooth scrolling by default enabled in IE9 in Windows 7. Fixed scrolling in IE 5 in Windows 2000

Comment: How to enable/disable Smooth Scrolling in IE settings http://www.granneman.com/webdev/browsers/internetexplorer/smoothscrolling/