# Jerky Parallax in IE7-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I've introduced a basic parallax effect into a site that I'm developing. It runs smoothly in Chrome, Firefox and IE9; but it's really jerky in IE7 and IE8. I've looked at far more complicated sites and I don't see anything like the 'jerkiness' that I'm getting. I'm only using two images with a scanline texture over the top.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

```css
#intro {
    background: url(../img/graphics/top-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 768px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#second {
    background: url(../img/graphics/content-bg-2.jpg) center no-repeat fixed;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-width: 1200px;
    min-height: 768px;
    height: 4800px;
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code? Have this sites in IE7/8 "jerky" effect?

Comment: here's the parallax plugin i'm using..
http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/demos/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/
i've added the css above

Answer (score 0):

Please check this setting (in comments) [How can I check browser smooth scrolling support via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991668/how-can-i-check-browser-smooth-scrolling-support-via-javascript) .

If it disabled - it is normal.

As I understand this http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/demos/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/ is example, not your code. And if smooth scrolling is disabled - it has "jerky" effect (I have disabled smooth scrolling is Chrome, Opera and IE8).

Reason in scrolling principle. If this setting is disabled - it works like **permanent +100px**. If it is enabled - it works like **10 times per 50ms, each time +10px**.

---

**UPDATE**

For more performance you can do this things:

- Write your own code without plugins
- Build events calls based on current scrollTop interval, not on every scroll call
- Cache jquery nodes at the beginning
- **Main principle - less node manipulations = more performance**

I have written similar effect on jquery - you can see it here http://www.thecommoditycode.com/ambersoftware/ and use it principles

Comment: I've checked and disabled it but I still get the same problem. Considering most parallax sites don't have this problem I'm assuming its my code. Any other ideas, if I sent you a staging link would you be able to have a look?

Comment: No, you need to enable this setting to not having problems

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I had it enabled and it was jerky anyway

Comment: Post your code and give a comparison with another site to know where is real problem (full html + css + js).

Comment: Hm. I have jerky effect in Firefox. You problem in performance. And IE8 as a weakest browser have bigger problems.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix this? :/

Comment: I have updated answer - I think the only thing you can do - write your own code without plugins

Comment: Sadly I have no where near the knowledge to write my own code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Firefox used to, and may still do, have a bug with fixed background images. There is a possible fix, which I have not tested: http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/faster-scrolling-parallax-websites-in-firefox/

Answer (score -1):

I know that it's a bit late to answer this but it might help people in the future - the problem is that you're using:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

to make the images behind the parallax fullscreen, you need to use another method.

Remove this code your parallax will be lovely and smooth.

Comment: We don't cripple modern browsers for the sake of IE. IE<9 cannot handle those properties and will only ignore them. This would not be the solution.

Comment: Actually Rob, parallax sites using 'cover' can be jerky in the most modern version of Chrome so you're wrong there.

Comment: The problem is with IE, not Chrome. Only IE is the issue here.

Comment: I've just double checked this by adding the code back in - the 'cover' made the Parallax jerky again - turns out it's actually conflicting with some other CSS that was giving the parallax window a fixed height... a slice of humble pie please.  The conflict was only with Chrome though, no other browser.